# How to prevent duplicate values in a arraycollection?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have a `Session` entity which has a integer `$num` property. Two or more Sessions can have the same `$num` value. A `Session` may belong to several `Group` entities.

A `Group` can also have several sessions attached to it. When creating a `Group`, users can assign Sessions that it contains into an `ArrayCollection` but a group cannot have two sessions with the same `$num` value.

How can I enforce this restriction using the Symfony Form component, specifically using the [`CollectionType`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) field type?

EDIT:

Here's the (unidirectional) many-to-many mapping from Group to Session:

```
# Group.orm.yml
manyToMany:
    sessions:
        targetEntity: Session
        joinTable:
            name: sessiongroups_sessions
            joinColumns:
                group_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:        
                session_num:
                    referencedColumnName: num
```

I set `$num` as referenced column in the `inverseJoinColumn` (instead of `id`), so the `sessiongroups_sessions` table can never have two or more rows with the same group id referencing Sessions with the same `$num` value.

<strike>This is fine from the database perspective</strike> (EDIT: apparently not, I assumed this would work without trying it out), I need to know how I can enforce this in the **form** where users specify sessions of a group.

I know there is a constraint called [`Collection`](http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/constraints/Collection.html#extrafieldsmessage), but it needs a validator specified for every key of the collection. I know I can build the form to add sessions to the collection like this:

```
$group = new Group();
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($group)->add('sessions', CollectionType::class,
array('entry_type' => EntityType::class, 'entry_options' => array('class' => AppBundle:Group));
```

How can I specify a constraint here that ensures the **collection never holds two sessions with the same `$num` value?**

Comment: Please start with showing some code. This is your second question in that regard.

Comment: I don't even know where to begin. I can post the mapping information for the many to many association between Session and Group if that helps @colburton

Comment: There's so much to the form component in symfony that it's confusing me

Comment: Start with the `$builder->add('something', CollectionType::class ...)` bit.

Comment: @colburton Ok I've added some code

Comment: you need a custom class validator

Comment: @PeterPopelyskho Can you link me to a tutorial or the doc for that?

Comment: @MrWarlock616 [here you go](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need and [indexed association](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html#mapping-indexed-associations)

Assuming you're using yaml mapping, your association in `Group` entity could look like this:

```
  manyToMany:
    sessions:
      targetEntity: Session
      mappedBy: groups
      indexBy: num
```

Then you need to modify your setters to use `$num` as keys too. More info in Doctrine Documentation under link mentioned above.

Obviously you also need to handle a case when someone's trying to add  a `Session` with existing `$num` value depending on your needs.

@edit:

> I set $num as referenced column in the inverseJoinColumn, (...) This is fine from the database perspective

No, it's not. `$num` is not unique across `Session` entities therefore having a `$num` value in `Group` entity, you cannot identify any particular `Session` instance. It needs to be a unique key.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look. Meanwhile, can you please see my edits, and help me achieve this using the Form component?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know inverseJoinColumn expects the column to be unique in the related entity. Thanks! @Jakub Matczak

Comment: Hey I checked and Doctrine allows me to specify num as the inverseJoinColumn. This will enforce the restriction I want in the DB wouldn't it, since both the group_id and session_num will be PKs in the resulting sessiongroups_sessions table?

Comment: Think about SQL. How would look like an SQL query that would get a `Session` associated with a `Group`? If you do a `SELECT * FROM Session WHERE num = ?`, you will get a few `Session`s for a single `num` value and you won't know which one is the correct one.

Comment: The Group is the owning side of the relationship so I was planning to retrieve all the sessions in a group by hydrating the sessions arraycollection (which is in the Group entity)

Comment: but it's important to me that the arraycollection doesn't ever have two sessions with the same num value.

Comment: But you can't identify which `Session` with a particular `$num` value is assigned to a particular `Group`. Let's say there's a `Group1` that is associated with `$num=123`, and there are more than one Session that has `$num=123`. Which one of them is the one that is assigned to this Group?.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. That can easily be solved by including `$num` in the PK of the `Session` table.

Comment: But Doctrine only allows 'ASSIGNED' id generator for each PK column, so that's again a bad idea :/

Comment: I've already gave you solution. I don't know why you're trying it to do the way it can't be done.

Comment: I'm exploring my options. I'll try your solution too